# Why Python JSON output always added with escape string?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, escaping

the code

```
import json

jsonData = {
    'url' : 'test/file.jpg'
}

arrayData = json.dumps(jsonData)

# load the json to a string
resp = json.loads(arrayData)

resp['url'] = resp['url'].replace(r'/',r'\/')

print('without JSON output:',resp['url'])

jsonDataNew = [
    {'url' : str(resp['url'])}
]

json_data = json.dumps(jsonDataNew)
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
print('with JSON output')
print(json_data)
```

the output

```
without JSON output: test\/file.jpg
with JSON output
[{'url': 'test\\/file.jpg'}]
```

the desired output would be

```
with JSON output
[{'url': 'test\/file.jpg'}]
```

no matter how, im not able to remove the escape in the JSON output, even converted into JSON file. is this something unavoidable in Python?

Comment: you mean you want it like \ instead of \\?

Comment: this is the input "test/file.jpg" i want to it be "test\/file.jpg" in JSON output

Comment: hmm, if i print `json_data[0]['url']` at the end, I do get test\/file.jpg as expected.

Comment: print as string it looks perfect. can you try to print as JSON format? the extra / appears.

Comment: hmm, good question. because `json.loads('[{"url": "test\/file.jpg"}]')` totally works too.

Comment: maybe `json_data = json_data.replace('\\\\', '\\')`?

Comment: You are printing a Python object, which always **displays** strings in dictionaries and lists as their `repr()` with literal backslashes escaped to show they are literal backslashes.  Other non-printable characters will have escape codes as well, like newlines (\n) and carriage returns (\r).  There is only one backslash in the string.  `print(json_data['url'])` to see the `str()` of the string which will display only one backslash.

Comment: @rv.kvetch json_data = json_data.replace('\\\\', '\\') return more \ in the output.

Comment: @MarkTolonen what do you suggest if we need to remove the escape backslash in JSON output?

Answer (score 1):

This is because it uses backslash to escape backslash. In that sense, the double backslash you saw is actually interpreted as a single character.

For an example,

```
>>> a = 'test\\'
>>> a
'test\\'
>>> print(a)
test\
```

You can read up for more on `repr`

On the other hand, if what you want to do is to escape the forward slashes. Perhaps the easier and cleaner solution is to use [ujson](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson).

```
import ujson
    
jsonData = {
   'url' : 'test/file.jpg'
} 
json_data = ujson.dumps(jsonData, escape_forward_slashes=True)
print(json_data)
```

The output will be :

```
{"url":"test\/file.jpg"}
```

Comment: ujson with escape_forword_slashes does the job! what if in the value we need to have 2 different formats one with escape and one without? example:
`
#with JSON output
[
{'url': ['test\/file.jpg', 'test/file.jpg']
]
`